# Analytic Philosophy in India

Tags: eastern-philosophy

After studying Jonardon Ganeri's Philosophy in Classical India, one is made to think whether there are applications of Indian classical Navya-Nyaya  logic in Analytic Philosophy? What is the appropriateness of this? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: seems so: [wikipedia's comparison to modern logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navya-Ny%C4%81ya#Comparisons_to_modern_logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This at least to some people seems a very appropriate thought.

Arindam Chakrabarti is purposing your idea in „Telling as Letting Know“. You might want to read it if you are interested in the topic.

The debate is divided in two subdebates. The first one is the one Ganeri is taking part in, in arguing if in this case indian Philosophy can be transfered to western Philosophy or vice versa in a generall aproach. The second debate is the specific question if Navya-Nyaya logic can be applied in Analytic Philosophy.

I don't know how appropriate it is overall, it's a debate that is still going and is rather new.